# Cannot subclass WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, subclass, init, wkwebview

I am trying to subclass WKWebView. When I implement my own initializer, I got this error:

```
'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'WKWebView'
```

Ok, that is well known that we have to implement it for subclasses of UIView. For a direct subclass of UIView it works just implementing it, but with WKWebView it does not seem so simple. I followed the Fix-it hint, and this snippet is added to the code:

```
required @availability(*, unavailable) convenience init!(coder: NSCoder!) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

So I get a class like the following:

```
import WebKit


class TSWebView : WKWebView {

    let s: String
    let i: Int

    init(s: String, i: Int) {
        self.s = s
        self.i = i
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
    }

    required @availability(*, unavailable) convenience init!(coder: NSCoder!) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

However, when I do this I get these four other errors:

```
expected declaration
    required @availability(*, unavailable) convenience init!(coder: NSCoder!) {

consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
    required @availability(*, unavailable) convenience init!(coder: NSCoder!) {

cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable
    required @availability(*, unavailable) convenience init!(coder: NSCoder!) {

'required' modifier must be present on all overrides of a required initializer
    required @availability(*, unavailable) convenience init!(coder: NSCoder!) {
```

Any ideas? My Xcode Version is 6.1.1 (6A2008a). Thanks a lot.

Comment: You implemented the method in a way that throws errors claiming that the method is not actually implemented. That doesn't seem likely to be a good idea.

Comment: Actually, that method snipped is automatically added by Xcode when using the Fix-It hint. Removing the @availability tag gives other problems, see below.

Answer (score 5):

Just override the regular initialization like this. This worked for me, Swift 5.

```
override init(frame: CGRect, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration) {
    super.init(frame: frame, configuration: configuration)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is totes possible. You must only use convenience initializers and properties with default values set:

```
import WebKit
class MPWebView : WKWebView {
    var transparent: Bool = false

    convenience init(config: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()) {
       let prefs = WKPreferences()
       prefs.plugInsEnabled = true // NPAPI for Flash, Java, Hangouts
       prefs.minimumFontSize = 14
       prefs.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
       config.preferences = prefs
       config.suppressesIncrementalRendering = false
       self.init(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: config)
    }

    convenience required init(url: NSURL) {
       self.init(config: nil)
       loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
    }
}
```

Comment: the unavailable init(coder) is landing in a future release (not in OSX 10.10.4 / iOS 9.3): https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/commit/198c24f0555e8894325ca08087e731afae4a8fd9

Comment: Could you please explain "totes"

Comment: Its slang for "totally" :-)

Comment: Yes I found it in urban dictionary. I'm too old. Totes.

Answer (score 2):

Try taking out the extra decorations:

```
import WebKit

class TSWebView : WKWebView {

    let s: String
    let i: Int

    init(s: String, i: Int) {
        self.s = s
        self.i = i
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
    }

    convenience init!(coder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder:coder)
    }
}
```

Although I'm guessing the whole point of the "availablity(*, unavailable)" is to make it so that you can't invoke the initializer (and hence can't effectively subclass WKWebView.

Comment: Yes, it seems like that is the point. In this case, I got these errors: error: cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable, error: 'init(coder:)' is unavailable, error: must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'WKWebView'
        super.init(coder:coder)