# Can't cast WKWebView to my custom subclass of the WKWebView in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, webkit

I created a custom subclass for my `WKWebView` in my project called MyWebView, but when I try to cast a `WKWebView` into a `MyWebView`, app crashes. What might be the issue?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import SwiftyJSON

class MyWebView: WKWebView {

    var requestUrl: String?
    var row: Int?
    var data: JSON?

}
```

This is where I make the cast:

```
func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if message.name == "callbackHandler"{

        let mywebview = message.webView as! MyWebView


    }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'WKWebView' (0x1a0717408) to 'MyProjectName.MyWebView' (0x10026b950).
```

Comment: As this is an old post, I think you already found a solution, but just in case anyone visits this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487821/cannot-subclass-wkwebview